# A Nice Combinatorial Problem

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, binomial-coefficients, extremal-combinatorics

Let $A=\{1,2,...,10\}$ and Let $\mathcal A = \{ T \subset A | |T|=4\}$.Consider an arbitrary function $f:\mathcal A \longrightarrow A$. Prove that there exists a subset $S$ of $A$ with five elements such that $f(S-\{r\}) \neq r$ for each $r \in S$

My idea is to use the fact $\binom{10}{4}$ is strictly smaller than $\binom{10}{5}$

Any hint is welcome to solve this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we use some pigeon hole type argument?

Comment: Consider the set $$B = \{ \{a,b,c,d, e \} \subseteq \{1,2, \cdots , 10 \}\ \big |\ \exists\   \{p,q,r,s \} \subseteq \{a,b,c,d, e \}\ \text {such that}\ f(\{p,q,r,s \}) = \{a,b,c,d, e \} \setminus \{p,q,r,s \} \}.$$ So every element of $B$ is of the form $\{a,b,c,d, f (\{a,b,c,d \}) \}$ i.e. $|B| \leq |\mathcal A| = \binom {10} {4} < \binom {10} {5}.$